# Secure access to SQL Azure

Tags: security, azure, azure-sql-database

What is the best way to create a secure connection to SQL Azure from a customer location?

We are currently using IP address and setting the firewall, but this is not very secure

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty much all you have with the Azure SQL Database offering today.  The TDS protocol is sent to the client over TLS so the transport is secured.

Note that you could theoretically create a "jump" or "bastion" host in Azure on a VM, and allow only connections to Azure SQL from the public VIP of that host, but I'd question how much more secure that is than what you have now.

Comment: What about this?

http://www.dotnetsolutions.co.uk/blog/connecting-to-sql-azure-without-changing-your-firewall

Comment: Sure, you could do that, but it seems awfully complicated for solving a problem that doesn't really exist. More moving parts to configure and that can fail as well.